# Why does my email validation script won't get recognized?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Hey so I am really new to HTML and Javascript. I got a task today to code an Email validation script. I think that my script should be fine but for some reason the website doesn't do anything when I click on my submit button. Here is my script:

HTML Form:

```
        <form class="contact-form" action="contact.html" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your name*" value="" id="name">
            <input type="email" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your email*" id="email">
            <input type="text" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your phone*" id="nummer">
            <textarea class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
            <p id="pflicht">* sind Pflichtfelder</p>
            <input type="button" class="contact-form-btn" value="Send" onclick="multiFunction()">
        </form>
```

And this is my function:

```
  function checkforEM(value){
        var laenge = value.length;//6

        if(value.indexOf("@") > 0){
            alert("@ ist da und nicht ganz vorne");
    }
        else{
            alert("@ ist nicht da oder auf Pos 1");
    }
        // das @ darf nicht am Ende sein
        // Frage: wie finde ich das raus?
        // Ich prüfe, ob der Indexwert von @ == 5 ist
        if(value.indexOf("@") == laenge - 1){ //5
            alert("@ ist am Ende");
    }   
        if(value.substring(value.length-3) == ".de"){
            alert("Ist eine .de-Top-Level-Domain");
    }else{
            alert("Ist keine .de-Top-Level-Domain");
          }
    }
```

I am using a function that combines mutiple functions at a time and it looks like this:

```
function multiFunction(){
  checkforBlank();
  checkforNu();
  checkforNa();
  checkforEM(this.value);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Check the console if you see an error. And where is `this.value` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `input type="email"`, then the email validation is done inside the browser and you do not need to write your own code for it. And to require a form field to be entered use the `required` attribute.

```
<input type="email" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your email*" id="email" required>
```